# Displaying Images in IOS

Tags: ios

proceeding with learning IOS, I wanted to try threading. I want to make a simple app with two buttons both of them downloading files from some sort of a website. 
But I am not able to figure it out what methods should be used to download and display them on storyboard?

Comment: Don't use threading. Use GCD https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use NSThread [link 1](http://www.xprogress.com/snippet-10-example-of-threading-in-iphone-sdk-objective-c-using-nsthread/) and [link 2](http://samplecodebank.blogspot.in/2011/05/nsthread-example_12.html) or go for [AfNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) this will provide you methods for asynch downloading.

Also you could use GCD and other library for dowloading files in asynch manner.